# Start synchronization of replication subscriber from command line or stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

We have a publisher and three subscribers. Two subscribers on the same LAN and a remote subscriber.

Every night we face an issue where replication goes down and won't restart.

The message says: FAILED for each publisher.

We are not sure what's happening, but at night we have mantainance plans scheduled and I suspect that may be causing our replications to go down...

What I'm trying to do, as a temporary patch, is to have a program to restart replication if the status says FAILED during more than 30 minutes.

We have already created a program that detects the current replication status so what we need now is to know how to programatically (stored procedure or command line) restart replication for each subscriber.

What we want is the exact functionality that we have when we open the Replication Monitor, right click on a subscriber and then click on "Start Synchronizing". Which, by the way, starts the replication correctly when we arrive at the office every morning.

Comment: Did you get any indication from the replication monitor on why the replication fails?

Comment: It just says Step Failed. Anyway, I would also like to know how the Monitor imlpements the "Start Synchronizing" functionality. When I click that button the replication starts working fine again.

Comment: So you click through to Details (Subscription Watch List tab, right click line with error, `View Details`) and see no details? You should see an Error Message at the very least (inside the table, column `Error Message`)? Or does it just say `FAILED` as you indicate in your question?

Comment: It says: Error messages:
The replication agent encountered a failure. See the previous job step history message or Replication Monitor for more information.  The step failed

Comment: Did you then go to the `Agents` tab in the Replication Monitor? What do you see there?

Comment: Anyway here's a list of all [Replication Stored Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174364.aspx). Here a list with [Replication Agent Executables Concepts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147886.aspx). I have no experience with this so I can't guide you any further. I will also flag this to move to dba.stackexchange.com because this sounds like typical DBA stuff.

Comment: Yes, I checked those but can't seem to find one about starting the merge again...

Comment: Just a thought, have you checked the SQL Profiler when you perform the action in Replication monitor? The profiler normally would show you what is being executed behind the scenes..

Comment: Yes, I did but I can't seem to see anything related. However, I see a new processes (replmerg.exe) is launched everytime I press the Start Synchronization button.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above, if you already have a program that detects the replication status and knows when it needs to start it again, you should be executing the `replmerge` from the command-line. The profiler could provide details about the command-line parameters and you can execute that command.

This [post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147839.aspx) has details about how you can start this command from the command-line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Already checked that and even tried to run from command line. BUT, can't find the correct arguments to use for the replmerg.exe

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson You can see the command line parameters when you investigate the proper SQL Server Agent jobs (SSMS, under the server tree on the left pane). If you get the proper job, right-click>properties, go to Jobs, and edit the correct step. This has command line parameters in it.

Comment: @TT THanks, but can't seem to find where ? Do you mean in the Sql Managment Studio?

Comment: Also I think you should already have the information needed for the parameters that are required. This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147886.aspx) has some more information about what are these required parameters, all the others seem to be optional.  You need to scroll down to the point where the merge example is.  Since you   have 3 subscribers, you may need to run the merge command 3 times, once for each subscriber.

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson Yes, SSMS = Sql Server Management Studio. Log on to the publication server, and in the left pane at the bottom should be `SQL Server Agent` entry in the tree.

Comment: @vmachan I have made some progress here. I was able to restart the replication from command line (!). However, I'm seeing only one problem left. I stop the replication from rep. monitor. I then start it from command line and replication monitor is able to figure out that the replication is running again and starts displaying the Delivery Rate and the correct icon (running state). However, when I put the mouse over the replication it displays the "Start syncrhonizing" option, as if the replication were not running.

Comment: That happens even if I restart the replication monitor. Even worst. If I stop the replication I launched from command line then the replication monitor shows the replication as running and the underlying stored procedures that I use to detect if a replication goes down also keep saying that it's running...

Comment: I suspect that what I need to do is launch the entire job, not just that step... what do you think?

Comment: I think you are right, although unsure about this situation, it seems the GUI and the command-line somehow are out-of-sync..  Did you just restart for one subscriber from the command-line? If so, that may be the reason why you see this happening, the synchronization needs to happen / start and finish for all subscribers and then the GUI should be in sync with command-line.

Answer (score 1):

I have used below code to sync merge publication in CMD.

Parameter details :-

> Publication - "RmoMergePub"
>
> Publisher - ".\SQLSERVER2014"
>
> Subscriber - ".\SQLEXPRESS2014"
>
> Distributor - ".\SQLSERVER2014"
>
> Publisher Database - "RMOser"
>
> Subscriber Database - "RMOcli"

```
  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\COM\REPLMERG.EXE" -Publication "RmoMergePub" -Publisher ".\SQLSERVER2014" -Subscriber ".\SQLEXPRESS2014" -Distributor ".\SQLSERVER2014" -PublisherDB "RMOser" -SubscriberDB "RMOcli" -PublisherSecurityMode 1  -OutputVerboseLevel 2  -SubscriberSecurityMode 1  -SubscriptionType 1 -DistributorSecurityMode 1  -Validate 3  -ParallelUploadDownload 1
```